# Como replicar uma linha com uma diferença de nomes nela? R

Tags: r

Eu tenho uma função e eu não queria ter que criar uma nova linha nela sempre que eu adicionar um novo objeto pra ela:

```r
a<- function(x1,x2,x3,x4){
res_x1= x1*4.95+x1
print("resultado x1")
print(res_x1)
res_x2= x2*4.95+x2
print("resultado x2")
print(res_x2)
res_x3= x3*4.95+x3
print("resultado x2")
print(res_x3)
res_x4= x4*4.95+x4
print("resultado x4")
print(res_x4)}
a(x1=10,x2=10,x3=10,x4=10)
```

A minha ideia é na hora que eu ter que adicionar outra variavel x5 por exemplo eu não tenha que escreve o codigo inteiro  pra a x5.

```r
res_x5= x5*4.95+x5
print("resultado x5")
print(res_x5)}
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer o r, copiar uma linha

```r
res_x1= x1*4.95+x1
print("resultado x1")
print(res_x1)"
```

e repetir ela dentro da function mudando os nomes x1 pra a quantidade de variaveis existentes? ex, se tiver 19 variaveis replicar essa linha 19 vezes porem uma com res_x5,res_x6,res_x7,rex_8,rex_9,rex_10,rex_11,rex_12,rex_13,rex_14,rex_15,rex_16,rex_17,rex_18,rex_19?

Eu tava pensando se é possivel criar um input "quantidade" e apartir desse input o r replica essas linhas com a quantidade desse input...

Obrigado pelas respotas porem me surgiu outra dúvida se eu tiver mais de um input, se eu usar

```
for(i in 1:length(input1),i in 1:length(input2)
for(i in 1:length(input1,input2))
```

Todas essas tentativas dão erro, tem como fazer um loop pra mais de um input? por exemplo:

```r
for(i in 1:length(input1,input2,input3))
  a <- (input1[i] * input2[i]) +z + g + h+i+ input3[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um loop `for()` com a função `paste()`:

```
a <- function(input)
{
  for(i in 1:length(input))
  {
    res <- input[i] * 4.95 + input[i]
    print(paste0('resultado x', i))
    print(res)
  }  
}

a(input = c(10, 10, 10, 10))
[1] "resultado x1"
[1] 59.5
[1] "resultado x2"
[1] 59.5
[1] "resultado x3"
[1] 59.5
[1] "resultado x4"
[1] 59.5
```

Comment: E quando eu tenho mais de 1 input pra passar dentro da function?? tentei numa function maior isso e deu erro Error in length()
  4 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1

Comment: pra função dele a entrada seria um vetor. Tipo `c(x1, x2, x3, x4)`

Comment: Correto, mas e se alem do resultado x, meu código tiver 2inputs, como eu faço o paste nesse caso?para cada input.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a ellipsis `...` na sua função. Dentro do argumento de uma função, `...` permite a função aceitar n argumentos —com nomes ou não. Veja como funciona a função em ação:

```
foo <- function(...){
  dots <- list(...)

  if(length(dots) == 0) return(cat("Nenhum argumento fornecido."))

  for(i in seq_along(dots)){
    res <- dots[[i]] * 4.95
    msg <- paste0("Resultado ", names(dots[i]), ": ", res, ".\n")
    cat(msg)
  }
}
```

Rodando `foo(x1=10, baz=1000, "boom"=19, 39)` no console, temos:

```
> foo(x1=10, baz=1000, "boom"=19, 39)
Resultado x1: 49.5.
Resultado baz: 4950.
Resultado boom: 94.05.
Resultado : 193.05.
```

Para usar `...` dentro da função, basta você transformar `...` em uma lista usando `list(...)`. Acima, você pode ver que eu transformei `...` em uma lista: `dots <- list(...)`. Neste caso, `dots` é um objeto de classe `list` onde cada elemento é um argumento fornecido.

Repare:

```
inDots <- function(...){dots <- list(...);return(dots);}
```

No console:

```
> inDots(x1=10, baz=1000, "boom"=19, 39)
$`x1`
[1] 10

$baz
[1] 1000

$boom
[1] 19

[[4]]
[1] 39
```

Veja como a função retorna cada argumento numa lista. A partir daí, você só precisa manipular essa lista como vemos em `foo`. É importante ressaltar que a depender do tipo de resultado que você queira obter com função, é preciso fazer uma análise de como você quer manejar certos objetos que podem vir a ser fornecidos em `foo` e que possam "quebrar" a sua função. Alguns exemplos são o uso de `NULL`, `NA` e `NaN`.